# Subclassing Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, subclass

As a RoR newbie, I'm trying to understand how/where to correctly subclass a gem.

I'm using the ruby-box gem (https://github.com/KonaTeam/ruby-box) in my application, and attempting to follow the example on their github page where they subclass session.rb in order to obtain a refreshed token as follows:

```
class MyBoxSession < RubyBox::Session
  # override call to refresh token so we can update the tokens store
  def refresh_token(refresh_token)
    ut = MyTokens.where(refresh_token: refresh_token, provider: 'box').first
    begin
      super
      ut.access_token = @access_token.token
      ut.refresh_token = @access_token.refresh_token
      ut.save!
    rescue OAuth2::Error => e
      # token pair must just be bad
      ut.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

I'm my box controller I use ruby-box to create the initial session, but I'm unclear on where I would add in the code above?  In the box controller, or do I need to pull in session.rb?

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you write just a *ruby* script, put the code inline. If you are using *rails* I believe in library **lib/**, and when you have need just call a library methods from a *controller/helper*. If the connection is persisted, initialize it once on startup.